# How many $8$ card hands with at least two cards from each suit can be made from a standard deck of $52$ cards?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> How many $8$ card hands with at least two cards from each suit can be made from a standard deck of $52$ cards?

I only got so far:

$${52\choose 8} - 1 =  752538149$$

I know for a fact that I am doing something wrong but I am not sure what.

Answer (score 2):

You are only choosing $8$ cards, but you should be choosing two from each suit.

To deconstruct this problem, you want to choose exactly two hearts, two diamonds, two clubs, and two spades. (That is the only way to have eight total cards with at least two from each suit.)

This can be done in $\binom{13}{2}$ ways per suite, or $\binom{13}{2}^4$ ways total.